# I need your help to fix an issue I'm having with a plugin called woo food, in woocommerce order page it does not filter custom status

Tags: wordpress

I need your help to fix an issue I'm having with a plugin called woo food, in woo commerce order page it does not filter custom status

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Woo food plugin is override hooks. So you need to find out it in woo food plugin the respective hooks